# Token validation stops working when using identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've added token (jwt) validation to my Web-API by following the steps in [this tutorial](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core). However, when I now try to add Asp.Net Identity to my application it somehow skips the token validation.

The token generation still works fine.

The API-controller-action that I am trying to access looks like this:

```
// GET api/users/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Authorize]
public User Get(int id)
{
   return _userService.FindById(id);
}
```

The "Authorize" attribute doesn't seem to make any difference after adding identity to my OWIN startup file, which looks like this:

```
var secretKey = "secret";
var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

var audience = "aud";
var issuer = "iss";

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
  IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

  ValidateIssuer = true,
  ValidIssuer = issuer,

  ValidateAudience = true,
  ValidAudience = audience,

  ValidateLifetime = true,

  ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
  AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
  AutomaticChallenge = true,
  TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
});

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseIdentity(); // When adding this the token-validation above seems to stop working...

var options = new TokenProviderOptions
{
  Audience = audience,
  Issuer = issuer,
  SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
};

app.UseMiddleware<TokenProviderMiddleware>(Options.Create(options));

app.UseMvc();
```

I've tried moving the Identity middleware above JwtBearerAuth, with no luck.

It always seems to skip validating my token, and even if I leave out the token I am able to reach the action, but when I remove the Identity middleware the token-validation starts working again.

Comment: Have you done `AddAuthentication()` and `AddIdentity()` in your `ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: I hadn't added AddAuthentication, but I just tried it with no luck...

`services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication();`